# Firebase Cloud Messaging sendEach function throws error: secretOrPrivateKey must be an asymmetric key when using RS256

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have been searching through the questions asked about this issue; however what I am looking for is a bit different.

While **send()** method of Firebase messaging works perfectly, `sendEach()` function throws the error. The desired behavior is that while it is certain other firebase functions in the code works as expected, sendEach function should send notification to all of the users in the arrays without an error. Note that also the function works in a bullMq worker.

We create an array of array of required data `(Array<Array<Message>>)`. The users in the first array which contains about 490 user get the notification. But whenever it starts to second array it gives this error. It should send the notification to all of the groups in the array.

Here is my code:

```js
const usedTokens: string[] = [];
const smallDatas: Array<Array<Message>> = [[]];

for (let index = 0; index < users.length; index++) {
  if (index % 10000 === 0) {
    logService.logNotification(
      `namedNotification: {title: ${title}, body: ${body}, language: ${language}, operation: ${operation}}. Process: ${
        index + 1
      }/${users.length}`
    );
  }
  const user = users[index];

  if (usedTokens.includes(user.notificationToken!)) {
    continue;
  }

  if (smallDatas[smallDatas.length - 1].length > 490) {
    smallDatas.push([]);
  }
  smallDatas[smallDatas.length - 1].push({
    token: user.notificationToken!,
    data,
    notification: {
      body: body.replaceAll("@name", user.username!),
      title: title.replaceAll("@name", user.username!),
    },
    apns: { payload: { aps: { sound: "res_notifysound.aiff" } } },
    android: { notification: { sound: "res_notifysound" } },
  });

  usedTokens.push(user.notificationToken!);
}

for (let index = 0; index < smallDatas.length; index++) {
  if (index % 100 === 0) {
    logService.logNotification(
      `namedNotification - send: {title: ${title}, body: ${body}, language: ${language}, operation: ${operation}}. Process: ${
        index + 1
      }/${smallDatas.length}`
    );
  }
  await messagingService
    .of("namedNotification")
    .sendEach(smallDatas[index])
    .catch((error) => console.log("Notification Error : " + error));
}
```

it gives this error sometimes. For example:

```js
const notificationDatas = [
[user1, user2,..., user491], 
[user492,...,user982],
[user983,...]
]
```

while the users in the first array of notificationDatas array get the message, other users cant get because it gives this error. I couldn't understand how is it possible when the firebase works for the first array, it doesnt for the other arrays

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sadly, I am also having the same issue. Code usage is similar, when sending to 1 user, I don't get issue, but I get when sending in batch to all users.